# C++ Class initialization with pointer as constructor param

Tags: c++, string, char

Below is a C++ class I wrote,

```
class MyString:public string{
  public:
  MyString(string s):string(s){}
};

int main()
{
  MyString s1("abc");
  MyString s2 = "cdf";
  return 0;
}
```

In the above code the line `My String s2 = "cdf"` cannot compile, however if I change the constructor parameter of MyString class to `public:MyString(const char s[]):string(s){}` then this line will compile. Why is that? Isn't string and char[] the same thing in C++?

Thanks,

Comment: _"Isn't string and char[] the same thing in C++?"_ No.

Comment: I would also lookup and read about `const` and references - Makes the code faster

Comment: Perhaps you should read the error, sometimes they are quite informative and actually tells you what's wrong with your code...

Comment: @juanchopanza And there's no longer a comment about that shown in the comments;)

Comment: You can remove `string` from your code, too, in order to get to the core issue. Anyhow, check out what an implicit conversion is.

Comment: Won't you need to add a = operator method?

Comment: No, it's implicitly created, @AndrewTruckle.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyString s2 = "cdf"
```

Doing this equates s2 as a string literal having value "cdf". But this is wrong, since `MyString` is your own data type, and you equated it with a variable of type `char *`.

If you want to use the equal sign while initialization, you need to do:

```
MyString s2 = MyString(std::string("cdf"));
```

This calls your constructor with parameter as string "cdf", and the object is copied to s2.

String and char are totally different! String is a derived datatype, and is a part of the C++ Standard Library, whereas a `char` is just an array of character. Read about `string` here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: String literals are not of type `const char *`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Okay. Can you edit the answer, so it can be clearer. Since what I know is it is of type char*.

Comment: First of all, you must distinguish more clearly between `const` and non-`const`. As for string literals, they are **arrays**. `"cdf"` is of type `char const[4]`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl but if we do `char *s = "cdf";`, i declares a string literal, which is a const. Where am I confusing?

Comment: `char *s = "cdf";` is a deprecated conversion which you should not use. In the case of `char const* s = "cdf"`, a simple conversion from the array to a pointer to the first element of the array takes place. This does not change the fact that the source of the conversion is an array.

Comment: thanks, so you can pass a constructor parameter using "=" operator?

Comment: @Huanyan sorry, I just messed up with some concepts. You cannot pass parameters using `=`, all you can do is assign the variable the value from another variable of the same type, or after typecasting it. I have edited the answer, and now it is correct. have a look.

Comment: @SahilArora thanks, but why `MyString s2 = "cdf"` works when the constructor parameter is `const char s[]` instead of `string s`? s2 and "cdf" are still not of the same type right?